# How to "docker-compose build" a service from code located in local git repository?

Tags: docker, git, docker-compose

I have a git repository placed in local file system at `/home/nou/code/lib.git`
Also I have `/home/nou/docker-compose.yaml` that is used to deploy a service based on the code from the repo:

```
version: '2'
services:
  lib:
    container_name: lib
    build: git://./code/lib.git/
    #build: git://./code/lib.git
    #build: git:///home/nou/code/lib.git/
    #build: git://file:///home/nou/code/lib.git/
```

As you can see, am trying to build lib service from the local git repo, but the only result I observe is such error (or similar):

```
nou@ubuntu:~/$ docker-compose build
Building lib
ERROR: error fetching: fatal: unable to connect to .:
.: No address associated with hostname

: exit status 128
```

How can I use local git repo to build services using docker-compose?

Comment: git protocol wait a hostname, if you want to use local path, use the file protocol, your 4th attempt is nearly correct, just drop the git:// before file://. In brief: `build: file:///home/nou/code/lib.git/` should do

Comment: @Tensibai but with that suggestion how does composer know it should be using git? :)

Comment: @DanCornilescu well it's an uri and not a path... Anyway if it is a repo, that a valid path for build context also. If there's another need, it should be stated

Comment: I believe `git://` is essential in this config line for the repo to be pulled (using git) before the build is actually executed. In other words - not a plain URI, but a git URI.

Comment: @DanCornilescu can you extend on the need to pull a repo already here? There's something bothering me in the wish to pull into local something already there...

Comment: My understanding is that the intention is to pull that git repo... If it's not the case - pls disregard my comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are specifically after (building from a bare repository on a local filesystem) isn't functionality offered by Docker, and by extension, docker-compose. Docker supports building from a few different URLs, but not bare repositories on local filesystems. You can try a few workarounds:

- Build straight from Github: `docker build https://github.com/docker/rootfs.git`
- Run a Git daemon to use the `git://` protocol: `git daemon --base-path=. --export-all` (in `/home/nou/code`)
- Running a Git daemon from within Docker, mounting your bare repository as a volume and building inside it via a mounted Docker socket
- Converting your bare repository to a normal one

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#build-with-url

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you. Git daemon works for me.(My current workaround is to clone into temporary directory and remove it after docker-compose goes down)

Comment: Sad to say, but docker can't clone daemon-hosted `git://localhost/lib.git` due to dumb git `bad pack header` error. At the same time I can clone it using `git clone`...

Comment: I've updated the command for `git daemon` to properly export your repository, you should be able to `docker build git://localhost/lib.git` after starting the daemon with the updated command.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this, it works for me:

1. Create a user named "git"

   ```
   $ sudo adduser git
   $ su git
   $ cd ~
   $ mkdir .ssh && chmod 700 .ssh
   $ touch .ssh/authorized_keys && chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
   ```
2. If you don't have ssh keys for "nou" user then, from "nou" user run

   ```
   $ ssh-keygen
   ```

   and accept all defaults.
3. Add "nou" user's ssh public key to git user ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

   ```
   $ sudo cat nou_user_home/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> git_user_home/.ssh/authorized_keys
   ```

After this try below command from "nou" user:

```
docker build git@localhost:/home/nou/code/lib.git
```

If `Dockerfile` is not at the root of cloned repository then:

```
docker build -f folder_containing_dockerfile/Dockerfile 
git@localhost:/home/nou/code/lib.git
```

If this all works fine then you can try with your `docker-compose` file.